# Process.Start() creating infinite windows

Tags: c#, process, cmd, system.diagnostics

I want to use a command prompt command through one of my c# programs, so I looked up some simple coding. I literally pulled 4 lines of code which create a new instance of the process class and processstartinfo class, then sets the filename to cmd and the argument to my command. As soon as process.Start() is called, instead of creating just one window as expected, an infinite number of command prompt windows open, to the point where I have to restart my computer. I might add that I isolated the code to its own program to be sure it wasn't any outside code of my program creating this effect, and I still got the same result. Any ideas?

Edit: Excluding the main method/ class, this is the exact code I used. It was pulled word for word from online (except for the arguments):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C tree";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: Maybe show us the offending code?

Comment: put your code if it have some problem. otherwise it seems to be some virus infection in your pc.

Comment: Infinite windows?  You have limited memory.

Comment: Kindly use paragraphs next time, it makes your questions more readable

Comment: Adding breakpoint's could help

Comment: Alright, added code to first post. And @Shai, as much as I appreciate your 'help', there is really no need for separate paragraphs in a 5 sentence question.

Comment: @jaykreeler Keeping your questions well written/clear will help the community help *you*, not me, and if there's one thing I'd prefer to see is readable text, rather than a block of text. I still think your question looks scary. that's just me though.

Comment: The code that you are running in the command prompt isn't opening additional command prompts, so the problem is that the snippet of code you have displayed is being called over and over, not that running that one snippet of code will result in more than one shell being created.  You will need to provide the context that that snippet is in for us to determine why it's being called repeatedly.

Comment: @Servy That's the problem: there is no context. I literally enclosed the code you see in a main method and a class, with not a single other line of code in the program; hence the fact that I am confused as hell as to what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the code you are using it's impossible to tell.

Try using this instead

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(); 
info.Arguments = "/C echo your command"; 
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; 
info.CreateNoWindow = true; 
info.FileName = "cmd.exe"; 
Process.Start(info);
```

Or if your using it more than once make it into a method.

Comment: The only difference between this code and the one that I used is the fact that you make the window hidden. Now, I may not be an expert at coding, but common sense would dictate that taking a problem and making it invisible doesn't change the fact that it's still there (albeit invisible).

Comment: @jaykreeler True, but this is the solution I presented before you had posted any code, thus I had no idea what code you were running. This worked for me, so I guessed it was worth a shot.